# import labview vi into java

Tags: java, eclipse, labview

I've experienced to change labview VI into C# method by using interp assembly.

With this stuff, I could use labview VIs on visual studio.

Now, I'd like to use labview VI on eclipse platform, but I can't find any way.

Can I change labview VI into java method? or are there any ways to import labview VI into java?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No direct methods I am aware of. Indirect ones may include:

1. Running your LabVIEW program as TCP/IP (or pipe) server
2. Compiling LabVIEW project as a DLL and using, say, JNI

Comment: I can verify that NI has never created any "to JAVA" compiler for VIs. Some 3rd parties have written compilers for VIs, such as the one that compiles VIs for the Arduinos, but I've never heard of one for JAVA.

Comment: I wanted to remove tcp/ip interface between java and labview. Second one will be a solution. Thank you~

Comment: @김갑수 Depending on volume of data transfer and # of method calls JNI might be quite expensive. For low latencies and high volume data transfers, in my experience, pipes (Windows) are better than TCP/IP.

Comment: You mean, JNI is charged. Ok. I will try to figure out pipe.